# Ion-button click working in browser and simulator, not on real device

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an app, and the (click) event does not seem to work on the real device.

The HTML of tab1.

```
<ion-button (click)="favorites(article)" tappable *ngIf="!checkFavorite(article.url)" shape="round"><ion-icon name='heart'></ion-icon></ion-button>
```

in tab1.page.ts

```
import { FirebaseService } from '../firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  constructor(public data: FirebaseService){       
  }

favorites(article) {
    this.data.addToFav(article) ;
  }
```

in firebase.service.ts

```
addToFav(object) {
    this.db.collection("favorites").add({
      "title":object["title"],
      "url":object["url"],
      "user":this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid,
      "author":object["author"],
      "image":object["urlToImage"],
      "time":object["publishedAt"],
      "source":object["source"]["name"],
      "description":object["description"]
    }).then(data => {
      console.log("Favorite added.");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error adding favorite.");
    })   
}
```

I tried moving around the (click) event in the html and added the tappable. However no luck on the real device. It works fine on the simulator and on in the browser - with no errors when clicked.

Both functions seem to be called correctly, however no item is written into the database?

Comment: try adding a `console.log` to the function `favorites(article) {...}` and connect your device in debugger mode and test it.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/developer-tips/) for how to debug the app.

Comment: @AdarshMohan I did that, and both functions are called correctly. However no item is written into the database?

Comment: Are you able to connect to fire base from your app? Check your connection

Comment: So it looks like there is a problem with the login on the real device. When I log out on the simulator, the app behaves the same as on the phone. So it never logs in on the phone, as the “logged in” message never appears.

Comment: So it look like something’s wrong with your apps firebase configurations.